# Block incoming and outgoing connections to a program in macOS

Tags: macos, firewall

Is there a way that I can block incoming and outgoing connections, both LAN and WAN to / from a program in macOS?

(I'm running Yosemite 10.10, but I guess it would be similar across OS versions)

Comment: [OS X Yosemite: Firewall pane of Security & Privacy preferences](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18635?locale=en_US)

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, i could only see how to block incoming connections using the Firewall, can i block outgoing as well ?  Also does the firewall work for LAN connections as well as WAN ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Radio Silence](https://radiosilenceapp.com/) does exactly this — it's an outbound firewall that you can use to blacklist outgoing traffic from particular apps. [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) can also [filter inbound](https://www.obdev.at/support/index.html?product=LS&topic=faq&entry=245442242578661) as well as outbound connections.

Comment: Thanks im currently using Radio silence, but as far as i can tell its only an outbound firewall is that correct ?  What im looking at doing now is using radio silence to block outgoing and OSX's firewall to block incoming, but it feels and bit convoluted, is there one applications that would do both ?

Comment: Yes, Little Snitch can filter both inbound and outbound connections (see updated link in answer)

Comment: Currently using Little Snitch for your exact use-case. It controls both incoming and outgoing connections.